# facebook comments words expanding

Tags: facebook, comments, grammar

I created an app and installed it on a page. In this app, I installed the comments plugin specifying the data-href parameters as follows:

`http://www.facebook.com/{my_page_username}?sk=app_{my_app_id}`

It seems that facebook enabled the grammar filter by default and is erroneously expanding some words.

How can I disable the grammar filter?

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in the 'settings' section of the plugin. The real question is how to get to that section.

The only way I know of, is when actually posting a comment (so, you're at a comment box at the end of your article now), and you're a moderator, in the upper-right cornet you have a 'settings' link.

http://www.ivanlistes.com/facebook-social-plugins-comments-problem-with-grammar-filter/